# Using Bayes Theorem Correctly?

Tags: probability, bayesian

This is not a homework problem, but one from the real world. To keep things g-rated, though, instead of a certain type of criminal I will say Blue Crystal Alien.

It is known that 3% of the population are actually Blue Crystal Aliens (BCA's).  Also, 1/3 of all BCA's are left-handed. In the general population, including BCA's and humans, 14% are left handed.  If someone is left handed, what is the probability that they are a BCA?

So, I get a prior of .03 times 1/3 equals .01 in the numerator. The denominator is, of course, .14.  So, 1/14 ~ 7% chance that any left hander is actually a BCA. This seems really high to me, more than doubling the chance in the gen pop. But I can't see any flaw in my use of Bayes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with your calculation.

To convince yourself, try imagining a population of $10,000$. $14$% or approximately one in seven people will be left handed, so about $1,428$ people. $300$ people are a BCA, $100$ of whom are left handed. So the probability that a left handed person will be a BCA is $100/1,428$ which is roughly $7$%.

Comment: Yeah, I get this. Now, change the 3% to 4% which I changed to simplify the math.  Then switch Blue Crystal Aliens to the actual group I was studying: pedophiles. About 14% of all men are left handed. If your babysitter is a left handed man, the P that they are in that group is nearly 10%  What the hell! It's the ramifications that get me, not the math.  Forget about babysitters: school teachers, soccer coaches, etc. That blows my mind. And is scary.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed.   Your calculations are correct.

$\def\P{\mathop{\sf P}} \begin{array}{rl}
\P(B) &= 3/100 \\[2ex]
\P(L) &= 14/100 \\[2ex]
\P(L\mid B) &= 1/3 \end{array}\qquad\qquad\begin{array}{|rl}
\P(B\mid L) & = \dfrac{\P(L\mid B)\P(B)}{\P(L)}\\[1ex]
&= \dfrac{1/3\cdot 3/100}{14/100}
\\[1ex] &= {1}/{14}
\end{array}$

If 1% of the population are left-handed blue crystal aliens, and 14% of the population are lefthanded, then 1/14 of the lefthanded population are blue crystal aliens.

Blue crystal aliens are rare, but *proportionately* many more of them are left-handed.